# What scrapy middleware should I use to capture and handle a 403 response?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and getting a 403 response without a redirect.  I want to do something different when this happens, what middleware should I use?  What I mean is I want to add custom behavior into a downloader middleware.  Should I subclass an existing part of the downloader stack or implement a custom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used Downloader Middleware `process_response` method:

```
class Process403:
     def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # if not 403, do nothing
        if response.status != 403:
            return response  
        # otherwise do something here
```

See [scrapy documentation for more info](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response):

> process_response() should either: return a Response object, return a Request object or raise a IgnoreRequest exception.